# How to calculate join in Spark with top N failed matches efficiently?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm writing a query for two dataframes for a product catalog, and sample of product codes which will contain duplicates, as well as codes not present in the catalog:

```
val productCatalogDf = List(
  (1, "RK111", "Category 1", "Product 1"),
  (2, "RK111", "Category 2", "Product 2"),
  (3, "RK112", "Category 2", "Product 3")
).toDF("id", "code", "category", "name")

val productSampleDf = List(
  ("RK111"),
  ("RK112"),
  ("RK113")
).toDF("code")
```

The sample data is expected to mostly belong all to one category, so I want to identify:

- The number of matches against the catalog for each category
- For each category with some match, the top N=100 most common values which failed to match that category. For example, above "RK112" does not match Category 1 so the list of failed matches for Category 1 will contain "RK112"

I'm able to do this with multiple passes over the data but I'm concerned about the performance - these are potentially very large tables. What is the most efficient way of collecting all of this information, e.g. can it be calculated with a single iteration over the (left) join between the two tables?

Code with multiple queries collecting data to the driver between each:

```
// get matches for each category
val distinctCodes = productSampleDf.groupBy("code").count()
val matches = distinctCodes.join(
  distinctCodes("code") === productCatalogDf("code")
)
.select("category", "count")
.groupBy("category", "count")
.sum("count")

// get failed matches
for (row <- matches.collect().toList) {
  val category = row.getAs[String]("category")
  
  val failedMatches = distinctCodes.join(
    productCatalogDf.filter(productCatalogDf("category") === category)
    distinctCodes("code") === productCatalogDf("code")
    "leftanti"
  )
  .orderBy("count")
  .limit(10)
  .collect()
}
```

Comment: Hi. I get the first question -  I think you have implemented it efficiently. However I'm struggling to understand the second question - could you explain "For each category with some match, the top N most common values which failed to match that category"

Comment: Okay ignore that. Just got it

Comment: Ok cool, I added an example of what should be included for a failed match

Answer (score 0):

I think you answered the first question efficiently but the second one will definitely run into problems at scale as you are essentially collecting that entire column and then iterating through it. Here's my take on both questions:

Starting with this:

```scala
val productCatalogDf = List(
  (1, "RK111", "Category 1", "Product 1"),
  ...
).toDF("id", "code", "category", "name")

val productSampleDf = List(
  ("RK111"),
  ("RK1112"),
  ("RK111"),
  ...
).toDF("code")
```

First deal with the duplicates in the catalog df and add a column for reference later:

```scala
val distinctCodes = productSampleDf.select("code").distinct.withColumn("x", lit(1))
```

Then join the catalog data onto the codes data:

```scala
val catalogDataWithCodes = productCatalogDf
  .join(distinctCodes, Seq("code"), "left)
```

Then calculate the number of matches against the catalog for each category:

```scala
val nCategoryMatches = catalogDataWithCodes
  .groupBy("category").agg(sum("x").as("match_count"))
```

Create a data frame of categories with at least one match

```scala
val categoriesWithMatch = nCategoryMatches.filter($"match_count">0)
```

Join above dataframe to main data frame to get the product code data and create a key column using the code + category pair.

```scala
val categoryCodes = catalogDataWithCodes
  .select("category", "code", "x")
  .join(categoriesWithMatch, Seq("category"), "inner")
  .withColumn("cat_code", concat($"category", $"code"))
```

Create a df with the count of each code within a category

```scala
val catCodeCounts = categoryCodes
  .groupBy("cat_code")
  .agg(count("cat_code").as("count_cat_code")
```

Join the counts back to the previous data frame and filter out the codes that had a match

```scala
val catCodesNoMatchsWithCounts = categoryCodes
   .join(catCodeCounts, Seq("cat_code"), "left")
   .filter($"x".isNull)
```

Now the *catCodesNoMatchsWithCounts* df contains the counts of the codes per category which did not have a match, for only the categories which had some match.

Its easy to now get the max (top 1) code which didn't match from here - I need to figure out how to get top n - still working on this just saving here for now.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I ended up using was to cache the join of the two data frames so it is possible to aggregate over it multiple times without re-computing the join.

```
// get matches for each category
val distinctCodes = productSampleDf.groupBy("code").count()
val join = distinctCodes.join(
  distinctCodes("code") === productCatalogDf("code"),
  "left"
)
.select("category", "count")
.cache()
```

First get the number of matches for each category:

```
val matches = join.groupBy("category")
  .filter(join("id").isNotNull)
  .sum("count")
  .collect()
```

Then get the failed matches for each category.  This is different to a top-N-per-group type of query because the groups may overlap.

```
val failedMatches = categories.flatMap(category =>
  join.groupBy("code")
    .agg(collect_set("category").as("categories"), first("count").as("count"))
    .filter(not(array_contains(col("categories"), category)))
    .orderBy(desc("count"))
    .limit(20)
    .collect()
)
```

There is still some repetition in this loop where the `collect_set` aggregation is repeated in each iteration of the loop - owing to some other constraints in the exact problem I'm working on it didn't make sense to cache this aggregation instead.